# Stored PL/SQL with select clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Tables :

```
//team
name
--------
fly
box
fire
```

Second table:

```
//player
name     pname
--------------
fly      abc
box      gba
fly      abcd
fly      john
```

So i try to created a PL/SQL with following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test( tname in VARCHAR2 )
IS
    total NUMBER := 0;
    p_np player.pname%TYPE;

    CURSOR c_player IS
         SELECT LISTAGG(p.pname,',') within group(order by p.pname)
         FROM player p where pname = tname;

BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) into total from player where name =tname;
    OPEN c_player;
    FETCH c_player into p_no;
    EXIT WHEN c_player%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( total || ':' || p_np );
    CLOSE c_player;
END test;
/
```

But when i run the script i just like pass an input in my sqlplus:

```
EXECUTE test('fly');
```

But my question is to use SELECT statement to show it out.
how should i do it?

Expected output:

```
3 : abc , abcd , john
```

but i need to use select statement

```
SELECT test('fly');
```

Comment: Sorry ,to Use `SELECT` statement means? you want like `SELECT test('fly') from dual;`

Comment: You have already all you need to put it into a simple select: 
select count(*) || ' : ' || LISTAGG(p.pname,',') within group(order by p.pname) FROM player p where name = &inputname;

Comment: Your PL/SQL code will not compile. You are missing the `RETURN` clause which is required for a function in PL/SQL.

Comment: @a_horse can compile and able to run. not neccesary to return if i using stored pl/sql

Comment: Your code will generate the error: `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following: return`. The keyword `return` **is** mandatory for a function. The line `FETCH c_player into p_no` will also not work because you did not declare a variable named `p_no` - only `p_np`

Comment: @user3664490 the code will compile. but wont run, without `return`! You will get `ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value`

Comment: okay i will test.
so how should i insert the return at ? in order to get the result i want. because i have to show out the player name